# Write multiple column names for pandas group by agg

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a group by in pandas and calculating the sum and average for multiple different columns.  Below is an example.

```
 grouped =df.groupby(['id']).agg({
                    'column1': ['sum','avg'],
                    'column2': ['sum','avg'],
                    'column3': ['sum','avg'],
                    'column4': ['sum','avg']
                    ....                  
                    'column8': ['sum','avg'] })
```

How do I avoid having to write every single column name. Is there a way to combine it with some type of function for all of the columns so I only can write ['sum', 'avg'] once?

Comment: If you want to use all columns, then you can use Dictionary Comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
df[cols_list].groupby(['id']).agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

Where `cols_list` is the list of your columns of interest plus your `id`, so it still can group: `['id','column1',...,'column8']` in your example.